# Alternative Links to Broken Links?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

today a good friend of mine had an offline website and wanted to have it that way an alternative link is provided when the other doesn't work.

E.G. Say sometimes a server works and you go to it frequently and then it is down. He wants an alternative link for that link if that server is not available, instead be redirected to another. I assume that JavaScript is required.

I have no code to provide since I don't know how. Please leave random code of yours as a representation of your answer. Hopefully I asked the question correctly for you to understand. :)

I will edit this question if it is not understandable.

Comment: there are numerous online dead link checkers. but I think that you are wanting to verify a link is valid before generating it on the html output. If so you may need some server tech to do this first. or at least some jquery/ajax calls. but this seems overly complex to just list links.  Can you provide an example of your desired outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way for this to work is to create an API endpoint on his server with the website that could be down, which just returns success. This is usually called a healthcheck.

Then on the website which links the broken one, use a JQuery POST to see if the healthcheck returns success or failure, and then change the HTML Dom accordingly. (So if other people link to your website, they would have to do this)

You can't redirect from the website that would be down from your point, because.... well it would be down....